# Какой виджет нужно кастомизировать , чтобы получить такой выпадающий список при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При нажатии на кнопку с крестиком вылетает вот такой список.  Хотелось бы сделать нечто подобное.

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема сделать список и по нажатию на кнопку его показать? RecyclerView + onClickListener + ObjectAnimator, например.

Comment: Просто он открывается поверх экрана и не на весь экран.

Comment: что значит "поверх экрана" ?

Comment: Открывается как клавиатура

Comment: Если вы говорите о том что я вижу на картинке и даже если представить что оно открывается с эффектом схожим на появление клавиатуры то все равно не вижу проблемы.

Comment: А как сделать такой размер у этого листа?

Comment: Вам нужно сделать список ListView или RecyclerView который будет по-умолчанию скрытый с alpha = 0 или visibility  = INSIVIBLE после чего при нажатии на копку с помощью анимации показать этот самый список с изминением alpha и translation

Comment: Насчет анимации и сокрытия я все понимаю. Меня интересует его размер,  он открывается не на весь экран,  занимает определенную часть

Comment: recyclerView.getLayoutParams().height = 20 - установить в коде либо android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_width="50dp" через xml

Comment: Ну хорошо. Спасибо за уделенное время

Comment: Если бы в вопросе был код можно было бы конкретней что то сказать, но если кода нету - это все что можна сказать!)

Comment: Да с кодом я сам разберусь,  тут дело в правильном выборе виджета. Я изначально подумал,  что это кастомный спиннер,  но потом понял что-то не сходится). Вот,  решил уточнить

Comment: @ВладСапожников, вообще похоже на bottomsheet

Comment: да, bottomsheet вобще изи, список сделал , слушатель повесил и готово!

Comment: Ну да,  похоже на него,  спасибо